# Access mdb Requires Password After FTP

Tags: ms-access, ftp, passwords, mdw

I have an Access mdb (Jet 4.0) that I'm FTPing. No password is required on the source mdb, but it's asking for one when I open the Ftp'd file. I have no idea what password it's looking for. FWIW, the ftp'd file size matches the source's file size exactly and since this is still in development, the source and target files are on my local box.

Can someone point me in the right direction on where to look?

Any insight is appreciated!
Scott C.

Comment: Do you have a way to verify a checksum on the file before/after transfer, such as with `Get-FileHash <filepath> -Algorithm MD5` (requires PowerShell v4)?

Comment: Thanks for the good idea, but come to find out I was reading the file as ASCII text and trashing the content of the file. Once I started reading the raw bytes all was good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved. I was reading the file as if it were ASCII text and trashing the content of the file. Once I realized this and just read the raw bytes, all was good.